# How to map XML file content to C# object(s)

Tags: c#, xml, file, dictionary, transfer

I am new to C# and I am trying to read an XML file and transfer its contents to C# object(s).

e.g. An example XML file could be:

```
<people>
    <person>
        <name>Person 1</name>
        <age>21</age>
    </person>
    <person>
        <name>Person 2</name>
        <age>22</age>
    </person>
</people>
```

.. could be mapped to an array of C# class called 'Person':

```
Person[] people;
```

Where a Person object could contain the following fields:

```
string name;
uint age;
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It sounds like you want use XML serialization. There is a lot already out there, but this is a pretty simple example.
[http://www.switchonthecode.com/tutorials/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization](http://web.archive.org/web/20130921190426/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization)

The snippet you want is about 1/4 of the way down:

```
XmlSerializer deserializer = new XmlSerializer(typeof(List<Movie>));
TextReader textReader = new StreamReader(@"C:\movie.xml");
List<Movie> movies; 
movies = (List<Movie>)deserializer.Deserialize(textReader);
textReader.Close();
```

Hopefully, this helps

Comment: The link to the xml-serialization code sample is now defunct... too bad. I think this is why people discourage linking to external sites on stackoverflow - but I too am a previous offender of this fopaux so am not really one to talk.

Comment: I posted the pertinent code in case the link died. Also, you can either google that code for the rest, or even try the wayback machine - https://web.archive.org/web/20130921190426/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization   I don't see any problems here....

Comment: http://web.archive.org/web/20130921190426/http://tech.pro/tutorial/798/csharp-tutorial-xml-serialization - wayback machine link

Comment: Dead link, downvoted, sorry (I know this was covered in the comments above but your answer hasn't been edited)

Comment: @JᴀʏMᴇᴇ You have more than 2000 points, which means you could do it yourself. That is the goal of reputation and points. Bad form just downvoting a valid answer that you can fix....

Comment: You need to remember to mark the object and its properties with the appropriate attributes [XmlRoot ("")], [XmlElement ("")], [XmlArray ("")].

Answer (score 2):

You can use the XmlSerializer class to serialize CLR Objects into XML. Here is the MSDN documentation with some sample code : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer.aspx

Comment: yep, xml serialization would be easiest